# redux form keeps not setting initial values multi form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-router, redux-form

ok I'll admit this is a bit of a hot mess but please bear with me.
Trying to understand why my redux-forms:
A: don't set ititialValues until I have set the store elsewhere in the app.. for eg. if I have another event that calls, getFirstTrip, then its in the store, and can load my form correctly with intialValues.

B: wipe themselves out when I click the router link again. Every time I click the router Link it behaves the same as the initial click.. even though the store is there.. the fields and initialValues are empty.

Using:
react-router, react-redux,  react-form

structure like this:
view.js

```
 const onSubmit = (formValues) => {
   props.updateTrip(formValues); //< traditional put action to api
 };

 useEffect(() => {
   props.getFutureTrip(); // traditional get action to api
   //the action dispatches the reducer to create the vacations.nextVacation.tripInfos

 }, []);

 return (
   <div>
     Register Page
     <TripRegistrationForm onSubmit={onSubmit} />
     <Highlight>
       {output}</Highlight> 
   </div>
 );
};

const mapStateToProps = state => {
return {
 initialValues: state.vacations.nextVacation.tripInfos //< this doesn't seem necessary. 
 }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps,{updateTrip, getFutureTrip}) (TripsRegistration);
```

Parent form TripRegistrationForm.js

```
class TripRegistrationForm extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    console.log("props", props);
    super(props);
  }

 render() {
    const { onSubmit, onChange} = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
          <childForm
            onChange={onChange}
            onSubmit={onSubmit}
          />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

TripRegistrationForm.propTypes = {
  onSubmit: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};

TripRegistrationForm = reduxForm({ form: "tripRegistration" })(TripRegistrationForm);

TripRegistrationForm = connect((state, ownProps) => ({
  initialValues: state.vacations.nextVacation.tripInfos
}))(TripRegistrationForm);


 export default TripRegistrationForm;
```

the form contents (these do populate initial values.. but not consistently... ever)
childForm.js

```
const RegistrationThirdPage = (props) => {
  const { handleSubmit, pristine, submitting, lockForm } = props;

  return (
    <form disabled={lockForm} className="ui form error" >
       <FormSection >
      
      <h2>
        Trip & Travel Details
      </h2>
 
      <Form.Group>
      
        <Field
          name="arriving"
          placeholder="Arriving"
          component={renderDatePicker}
          label="Select your arrival date"
        />
        <Field
          component={renderSelect}
          label="Number of Days"
          name="packageDays"
          options={singleArrayToKVs(colors)}
        />
      </Form.Group>

     
<Form.Group>
<div>
        <Button type="button" disabled={lockForm}  className="ui-button green" onClick={handleSubmit(values => props.onSubmit({...values, lockVacation:false}))}>
          Save my changes
        </Button>
</div><div>
        
        <Button type="submit" className="ui-button primary" disabled={bookVacation(pristine,submitting,lockForm)}
        onClick={handleSubmit(values => props.onSubmit({...values, lockVacation:true}))}>
       Book my vacation
        </Button>
        </div>
  </Form.Group>      
     </FormSection>
    </form>
  );
};
export default reduxForm({
  form: "tripRegistration", //Form name is same
  destroyOnUnmount: false,
  forceUnregisterOnUnmount: true, // <------ unregister fields on unmount
 // validate,
})(RegistrationThirdPage);
```

my actions look like this:

```
export const getFutureTrip = () => async (dispatch,getState) => {
  const{token} = getState().auth
  if(!token)
  return null; 
    const response = await axios.get(`/api/trip/futureTrip`,{headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
     }});
    console.log("response.data from getFutureTrip", response.data);
  
    dispatch({ type: GET_FUTURE_TRIP, payload: response.data });
  };
```

Comment: It's a little hard to understand where to even start looking. While you added a lot of code, I think you should reorganize it a little better.